# Selenium failing to download file to test repo - WINDOWS ONLY

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I've tried everything i can think of to get files to download into a folder in my test repository, works completely fine on mac but not on windows.

I've tried to set a different file_path for windows in case this is the problem but the downloads are still failing in chrome browser.

```
if platform.system() == "windows":
    test_downloads_directory = os.getcwd() + "\\tests\\data\\test_downloads"
else:
    test_downloads_directory = os.getcwd() + "/tests/data/test_downloads"
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "download.prompt_for_download": False,
         "download.default_directory": test_downloads_directory,
         "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

I've tried:

- Setting safe browsing
- Playing around with the file path